# Laptop display not working after updating to 18.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xubuntu, display, lenovo

I was running Xubuntu 17.10 on a Lenovo Legion Y720, using nvidia display drivers.

Everything worked great up until today that I updated to Xubuntu 18.04.

Now the laptop's screen shows a small unblinking cursor, and that's it. External Displays still work perfectly well.

The laptop's display isn't detected by xrandr or any similar program.

Grub and Xubuntu's splash screens, however, are displayed on the laptop display.

What could this be?

Thanks.

EDIT: Tried switching to TTY, just to see what happens - the tty is actually displayed on the laptop's screen :/

Comment: I have similar behavior on a Dell XPS using nvidia display drivers. In my case the laptop screen works fine, but after sleeping I can no longer use the laptop screen. My external monitors work fine. After a reboot I can use the laptop screen again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem, and I found the answer from [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391150) (which ultimately is just a link to [here](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/1033140/kubuntu-18-04-gives-black-screen-when-sddm-starts-no-login-/?offset=6)).

Edit your `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` and look for any commented lines. For some reason, the line containing `Driver "nvidia"` was commented out for me. Un-commenting it solved the issue.

If that doesn't work, then there are some more options in the linked post.

In my opinion, it's pretty silly that things like this can happen, where a random line in a config can get commented out or modified and cause such havoc. But I guess that's what you get for trying to upgrade instead of doing a fresh install.